# System.setproperty in multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

In my application(multithreaded application) , when GC is invoked, signal handler is called.In this handler, i am trying to set a property to suggest that GC has been invoked.

```
System.setProperty(key, "true") ;
```

The other threads read the key using

```
System.getProperty(key) ;
```

However, the problem occurs when the value of the key has been set to true while other threads of the application don't read this value as true(still it is false for them - the value which has been set during startup of the application)
I have debugged a number of times, but could not get it corrected. Need your suggestion on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This surprises me since both the `setProperty(...)` and `getProperty(...)` are `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized Object setProperty(String key, String value) {
    return put(key, value);
}
...
public synchronized V get(Object key) {
Entry tab[] = table;
int hash = key.hashCode();
int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    ...
}
```

- Is there a possibility that the threads are using a different value of `key`?  How do they get that value?  Is it a `final static` constant?
- Maybe the threads not testing for the value appropriately?  You should be doing something like this:

  ```
  if (Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty(key)) {
     ...
  }
  ```

Comment: I am reading the value of key from a configuration file which is the same througout the application.Hence , it is not possible that key will have different values.Regarding your second concern, i am using the same strategy. First reading the key then parsing its value

Comment: I'm grasping at straws @Mridul but have you tried making the `key` field volatile?  Are you sure that the threads are all seeing the same value of `key`?

Answer (score 0):

`System.setProperty` and `System.getProperty` assign your values to the `static` field of property in the System class so it's not working properly in multithreading.